# Excel vba macro to insert rows only functioning properly on first worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro to insert row of data above a date if that date isn't today.  It then adds today's date in the date column.  This is done across 30 worksheets but only the first worksheet is properly adding a row in the correct place and adding a date in the right cell.  The row should be inserted above A3" on all of them but the rest insert a row above "A4".  Below is the current code i am using, i think it may be a range problem but had no luck when testing that.

```
    Sub UpdatePrices()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, Ldate As String, DateRng As Range
Set DateRng = Sheets("AXP").Range("A3")    'date range is last date
Ldate = DateRng.Value    'defines ldate as most recent date


For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Select
    'Inserts a new row with containing today's Date and exclude sheets
    If Ldate <> Date And UCase(ws.Name) <> "DATA" And UCase(ws.Name) <> "UPDATE" Then
        ws.Rows(DateRng.Row).EntireRow.Insert
        ws.Cells(DateRng.Row, DateRng.Column).Offset(-1, 0) = Date
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: confused by your explanation here.. "The row should be inserted above A3" on all of them but the rest insert a row above "A4"". Do you mean the row should be inserted above A3 on the first worksheet and above A4 for all other sheets?

Comment: Sorry what i meant was all sheets should have a row inserted above A3, but only the first sheet which is AXP does so, the rest of the sheets insert their row above A4

Comment: Still not making sense. Let's do an example.... If your workbook has 3 sheets, where should the row be inserted on each of those 3 sheets...?

Comment: Above A3 on all 3 sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert a row, the row of your `DateRng` increases from 3 to 4. You should instead store the original row and column numbers in another variable so it doesn't change

```
DateRngRow = Sheets("AXP").Range("A3").Row    'date range is last date
DateRngCol = Sheets("AXP").Range("A3").Column
Ldate = Sheets("AXP").Range("A3").Value    'defines ldate as most recent date


For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Select
    'Inserts a new row with containing today's Date and exclude sheets
    If Ldate <> Date And UCase(ws.Name) <> "DATA" And UCase(ws.Name) <> "UPDATE" Then
        ws.Rows(DateRngRow).EntireRow.Insert
        ws.Cells(DateRngRow, DateRngCol) = Date
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Thank you.  I see now that adding a variable there can keep those cells fixed.  This worked.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working code under your specification. Also in the below code are a few *VERY* minor speed increases to your original code: Only call the Date function once, only check if last date is less then date once.

You say you will always insert a row above 3 and that the new rows column A should have the date, the below code will do that.

```
Sub UpdatePrices()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Ldate As Date
Dim Today As Date
Dim DateRng As Range

Set DateRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")    'date range is last date
Ldate = CDate(DateRng.Value)    'defines ldate as most recent date
Today = Date

If Ldate < Today Then

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Select
    'Inserts a new row with containing today's Date and exclude sheets

    If UCase(ws.Name) <> "DATA" And UCase(ws.Name) <> "UPDATE" Then
        ws.Rows(3).EntireRow.Insert
        ws.Cells(3, 1) = Today
    End If

Next

End If
End Sub
```